# Moloquent - Cloning a mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.1

I am using [Moloquent](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) and I want to create a new document from an existing document and save it by updating some fields of it.

For example, I have:

```
$originalObject = $this->someModel->find('someId');

$clonedObject = clone $originalObject;
$clonedObject->someField = 'Some Value';
$clonedObject->save()
```

But it removes the `originaObject` and just creates the new object only. I thought that the `_id` might be causing the issue so I also tried `unset($clonedObject->_id)` but still I am not able to achieve the desired result.

Can anyone please tell me how can I go about cloning an existing document into a new document?